# подключения к прокси - telethon python

Tags: telethon

делаю подключения прокси к скрипту и у меня вопрос по поводу

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import socks
client = TelegramClient('session_id', api_id='12123123', api_hash='0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef', proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, 'ip-proxy', port-proxy, 'логин', 'пароль'))
```

что такое - socks.SOCKS5 и надо ли мне его менять , и 'логин', 'пароль' что мне вписать ?
покупал proxy ipv4
на сайте **https://proxy-store.com/ru**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOCKS5 это протокол. Обычно для установки соединения (через прокси сервер с помощью SOCKS5) требуется аутентификация клиента (как раз логин и пароль ), но может и не требоваться. Это зависит как вы покупали прокси.